# How to remove start and end of the string in R?

Tags: r

I have this string `mystring`. I want to remove the begining and end of the string in one go and get the result. How do I do this ?

```
mystring <- c("new_DCLd_2_LTR_assembly.csv", "new_nonLTR_DCLd_2_assembly.csv"
)
```

result I want:

`DCLd_2_LTR_assembly` 
`nonLTR_DCLd_2_assembly`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to match zero or more character that are not a `_` (`[^_]*`) followed by a `_` from the start (`^`) of the string or (`|`) the `.` followed by `csv` and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
gsub("^[^_]*_|\\.csv", "", mystring)
#[1] "DCLd_2_LTR_assembly"    "nonLTR_DCLd_2_assembly"
```

---

Or use `sub` with capture groups

```
sub("^[^_]*_([^.]*)\\..*", "\\1", mystring)
```

Comment: Thanks . I was wondering if there is a way to do this also by indicating the number of characters to be removed from the start and end?

Comment: @MAPK `substr` from `stringr`

Comment: @MAPK as Wen said `substr(mystring, 5, nchar(mystring)-4)`

Comment: @Wen `substr` is a base R function. No need to load anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(stringr) 
str_sub(mystring,5,-5)
[1] "DCLd_2_LTR_assembly"    "nonLTR_DCLd_2_assembly"
```

Or just using (As per akrun )

```
substr(mystring, 5, nchar(mystring)-4)
```